IP3510/IP3506 don't fully cut off the power in standby
I'm experimenting with various "power bank" modules:

https://a.aliexpress.com/_EypXQkN
https://a.aliexpress.com/_EvgbXp3
https://a.aliexpress.com/_EIQPLzL

They all are based on either IP3510 or IP3506 chips. Both chips are supposed to cut off the output power when the key is double pressed. Quote from the datasheet: "If two short push is detected within 1s, IP5310 will close step-up convertor, SOC indicator LED and flashlight LED."
However, all the modules I have don't cut the power fully: about 2V still remain on the output pads. I have a 5V LED strip connected to those pads, and it dimly flickers 1-2 times per second when the module is in standby mode. Whereas the whole point of using those modules was to have an all-in-one solution: charger, 5V step-up, and power switch.
Is this expected? If it is, any advice on how to mitigate the issue? My current idea is to have a FET transistor at the output that will open when the output voltage is greater than 3–4V, but I would appreciate a sanity check / other ideas.
P.S. Supposedly, these chips (at least, IP5310) are also commonly used in flashlight drivers, but I haven't found the schematics or a driver itself to experiment with.

those could easily be fake

Have anyone experienced this? ... poll questions are not allowed here because they do not have a correct answer

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you checking the output voltage with a multimeter, or with an oscilloscope? If with a multimeter, the "off state" output voltage may actually be higher, but only in short pulses. This may complicate a solution.

Also, with the lights dimly flickering, is your concern power drainage? I.e. are you using a battery? Or is your concern that you want the LEDs to be dark?

@MathKeepsMeBusy, the goal is to have LEDs dark. Regarding the output voltage, I checked it with a multimeter first, but today I got a (fairly cheap) oscilloscope to double-check. I couldn't detect any pulses, though, the voltage seemed to be constant with some jitter

From comments.

the goal is to have LEDs dark.

If the goal is merely to keep the LEDs dark, then the simplest solution may be to add a pull-down resistor in between the output pins of your power module, or across the input pins to your LED string. This will draw a small amount of current, and probably keep the LEDs dark. I would try a 1 k\$\Omega\$ resistor first. The power consumption of this would be 5 x 5 / 1k = 25 mW when the LEDs are on, and possibly 2 x 2 / 1k = 4 mW when the LEDs are off. The resistor could possibly pull 2/1k = 2 mA current away from the LEDs (assuming that the output is current limited). If the LEDs still glow, you might try a smaller resistor. However, your losses will obviously be greater.
If the 1k works, and you want to decrease the power loss, you could try a larger resistor.
